# Decimal-Binary (JavaScript) Project

Tags: javascript, data-conversion

Basically a decimal-binary conversion. Code follows:

```
function convert() {
  var val = $("txtIn").value;
  if (val ===""){
    alert("No value entered for converstion.");
    return;
  }
  var cT = document.getElementsByName("tType");
  if (cT[0].checked) {
    //to Binary
    var dval = parseInt(val);
    if (isNaN(dval)) {
      alert("Input value is not a number!");
    } else if ((val % 1) !==0) {
      alert("Input value cannot include fraction or decimal");
    } else if (dval < 0) {
      alert("Input value must be a positive value.");
    } else {
      convertByArray(dval);
    }

  } ***else if (cT[1].checked)*** {
    //to decimal
    var bval = parseInt(val,2);
    if (isNaN(bval)) {
      alert("Input value is not a number!");
    } else if ((val % 1) !==0) {
      alert("Input value cannot include fraction or decimal");
    } else if (bval === 0 || dval === 1) {
      alert("Input value can only be 1s and 0s.");
    } else {
      convertByArray(dval);
    }
    //validity check, only 1s and 0s permitted, acknowledge spaces, cannot
    //be negative
  } else {
    alert("Please select a conversion type.");
  }
}
```

`cT[1]` (binary to decimal) is the section that's giving me trouble. When I run it in Firefox, it does return the input, just not the desired binary-to-decimal. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

The `dval` variable has its own converter function, so figured declare a `bval` and give its own as follows, but still not the desired output. No idea what I'm doing wrong:

```
function convertByArray(dval) {
  var rA = new Array();
  var r,i,j;

  i=0;
  while (dval > 0) {
    r = dval % 2; //remainder
    rA[i] =r;
    var nV = (dval - r) / 2;
    $("txtCalc").value = $("txtCalc").value +
      "Decimal " + dval + " divided by 2 = " + nV +
      " w/ Remainder of: " + r +"\n";
    i += 1;
    dval = nV;
  }
  for(j=rA.length-1; j>=0; j--) {
    $("txtOut").value = $("txtOut").value + rA[j];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't really follow all of that. If you are looking just to convert bin to dec, all it takes is one method `parseInt(num, radix)`.

### Demo

**This demo can convert decimal, binary, and hexadecimal**

```js
const convert = (rxFrom, rxTo, number) => parseInt(number, rxFrom).toString(rxTo);

let bin1 = 1101001;
let bin2 = 10100001;
let dec1 = 5641;
let dec2 = 97;
let hex1 = `ff96ca`;
let hex2 = `25dc5b`;
const bin2dec = convert(2, 10, bin1);
const bin2hex = convert(2, 16, bin2);
const dec2bin = convert(10, 2, dec1);
const dec2hex = convert(10, 16, dec2);
const hex2dec = convert(16, 10, hex1);
const hex2bin = convert(16, 2, hex2);

console.log(bin2dec);
console.log(bin2hex);
console.log(dec2bin);
console.log(dec2hex);
console.log(hex2dec);
console.log(hex2bin);
```